# LWC Restrict <lightning-input> to number with max value

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-inputfield, number

I have an input on an LWC which *has* to be a number and not greater than 2000. How do I go about achieving this, because whatever I've tried is not working.

This is my input definition:

```
<lightning-input
   name="maxrows"
   label="Number allowed (max 2000):"
   oncommit={handleMaxRowsFilter}
   value={maxrows}
   type="number"
></lightning-input>
```

and in my .js I've tried this, but it's not doing what I want.

```
maxrows = 200;
......... 
handleMaxRowsFilter(event) {
  this.maxrows =
    Number(event.target.value) > 2000 ? 2000 : event.target.value;
  console.log("in handleMaxRowsFilter: " + this.maxrows);
}
```

If I refresh the page, it does it correctly, but every time *afterwards* it just formats whatever number I put in. Why does it work first time, but not again afterwards?
I have a little video snip but can't add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely because event.target.value is a string, not a number, which might be causing problems. However, there's already a native built-in property that does what you want:

```
<lightning-input
   max="2000"
   name="maxrows"
   label="Number allowed (max 2000):"
   oncommit={handleMaxRowsFilter}
   value={maxrows}
   type="number"
></lightning-input>
```

Comment: That's so simple and works great :)